# Get multiple matches with tcl regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

How do I get all the matches in tcl using regexp command? For example I have a string as following

```
set line "foo \"aaa\"zz bar \"aaa:ccc\" ccc"
puts $line
foo "aaa"zz bar "aaa:ccc" ccc
```

I now want to get `aaa` and `aaa:ccc`. There could be any number of such matches.
I tried

```
regexp -all -inline {"(.*)"} $line 
{"aaa"zz bar "aaa:ccc"} {aaa"zz bar "aaa:ccc}
```

But as seen this didn't work. What's the right way to get multiple matches and match everything within double quotes?

Comment: With that I got 4 matches `regexp -all -inline {"([^"]*)"} $line
{"aaa"} aaa {"aaa:ccc"} aaa:ccc`

Comment: No, you got two matches. You just see the whole match + Group 1 value for each match.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that regular expressions are matched greedily, so they stop matching as late as possible. Try the pattern `"(.*?)"` instead.

Comment: @DonalFellows Yes, that worked too. Thank you. It's a great method to not match greedily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture all between two quotes with `"([^"]*)"` pattern. When using the pattern with `regexp -all -inline`:

```
set matches [regexp -all -inline {"([^"]*)"} $line]
```

you will get all overall match values and all the captured substrings.

You will have to post-process the matches in order to get the final list of captures:

```
set line "foo \"aaa\"zz bar \"aaa:ccc\" ccc"
set matches [regexp -all -inline {"([^"]*)"} $line]
set res {}
foreach {match capture} $matches {
    lappend res $capture
}
puts $res
```

See the [online Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/HOQIxS).

Output:

```
aaa aaa:ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate  method to extract the quoted strings is:

```
set unquoted [lmap quoted [regexp -all -inline {".*?"} $line] {string trim $quoted {"}}]
```

Or, split the string using quote as the delimiter, and take every *second* field.

```
set unquoted [lmap {a b} [split $line {"}] {set b}]
```

That gives you a trailing empty element since this `split` invocation results in a list with an odd number of elements.